# Lambda expression results in error CS1643: Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<HttpClient, TRepository>'

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, dotnet-httpclient

The following code results in the error message:

> error CS1643: Not all code paths return a value in lambda expression of type 'Func<HttpClient, TRepository>'

Here is the class:

```
public class HttpClientRegistrar<TIRepository,TRepository>
        where TIRepository : IHttpBaseRepository<TRepository>
        where TRepository : class
    {
        private readonly NGApiOptions _apiOptions;
        public HttpClientRegistrar(NGApiOptions apiOptions)
        {
            _apiOptions = apiOptions;
        }
        public void Register(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            /*------------------------------------------------------*/
            /* Add Repositories and BLLs for Dependency Injection   */
            /*------------------------------------------------------*/
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TIRepository, TRepository>(client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_apiOptions.BaseUrl);
            })
                .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder =>
                {
                    builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                    };
                });
            
        }
    }
```

I have read some other posts with the same error message, but I don't see any answers that fix my problem.

One other important note.  If instead of using generics I instead use an actual interface and class this code compiles.

The red error indicator appears after the following code

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TIRepository, TRepository>(client =>
```

Comment: Your lambda expression must return an instance of `TRepository`.

Comment: You might want to use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions-addhttpclient(microsoft-extensions-dependencyinjection-iservicecollection-system-string-system-action((system-net-http-httpclient)))

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue while trying to specify the BaseAddress of the client, getting a type error inside the lambda function:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TIRepository, TRepository>(client => 
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["BaseAddress"]));
```

It was a complex type error pointing out that the lambda function was failing to convert to the intended delegated type TRepository.

I would suggest the following:

1. Try writing the initialization without the lambda function:
   `builder.Services.AddHttpClient<TIRepository, TRepository>();`

See if there is an error. In my case, I forgot to specify in TRepository that I was implementing the interface TIRepository. That was the root cause of all of the errors.

2. Make sure that in TRepository, you're implementing the interface TIRepository:

`public class TRepository : TIRepository`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add the interface on the service I wanted to inject this for. I was loosing my mind.. +100